# FCM using JAVA Code using user's device token

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making chat application using firebase and i want to send push notification to user using FCM using Java code and not using Firebase Console.I have successfully obtained user's device token.

I tried using a service but i keep getting the following error.Can some please guide me

> onResponse: Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.
>
> ## Invalid (legacy) Server-key delivered or Sender is not authorized to perform request.
>
> ### Error 401

Here is my code

```
public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method is only generating push notification
    //It is same as we did in earlier posts
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Push Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

I have registered this service in my Manifest

Comment: Where   is your  JavaCode?

Comment: Is it your server side code giving the error? Can you show your server side code?